# Turn off serialization failure logging

Tags: postgresql, error-log, serialization

Is it possible to turn off serialization failure logging?  If so, how?

For example, my log is filled with this example:

```
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
GMT DETAIL:  Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during commit attempt.
GMT HINT:  The transaction might succeed if retried.
GMT STATEMENT:  COMMIT
```

`log_statement` is commented so left to the default `none`.

Comment: You cannot single out different types of ERRORs.  You can etiher get rid of all of them or see them all.  On the other hand, if this comes from a single user, you can disable the logging for it (but still, either all or none of them).

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The inability to suppress errors or filter into different logs based on SQLSTATE is a significant wart in PostgreSQL IMO. Typos by users get logged the same as many serious internal problems.

Comment: @CraigRinger Interesting.  I'll just add a mutex on these two queries in my application.  Probably more correct anyways.  Thank you.

Comment: Mutex was a horrible idea.  PostgreSQL manages it far better with retries.